# matplotlib scatter plotting over png

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, overlay, scatter-plot

I'm trying to make a scatter plot consisting of ~6 million points in an attempt to understand some sort of clustering.

When I try to do this in a simple scatter command, matplotlib complains about excessive memory. So I decided to plot 3000 points and then save the figure in .png format, clear the figure, load the saved .png with `imread()` and then overlay the next 3000 points.

I'm facing some padding issues and I do not understand how they've arisen. My code is a bit long since I'm parsing a lot of text files but below is a sample mockup code that replicates my thinking:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xlim(0,1000)
plt.ylim(-1000,1000)
plt.scatter(400,500,marker="+",c="r")
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.draw()
plt.savefig(r"C:\TMP\fig1.png")
plt.clf()
im = plt.imread(r"C:\TMP\fig1.png")
implot = plt.imshow(im, origin='upper', aspect='equal', extent=[0,1000,-1000,1000], zorder=0)
plt.scatter(600,500,marker="+",c="b")
plt.savefig(r"C:\TMP\fig2.png")
plt.close(fig)
```

The outcome is something that I don't understand how to interpret. Obviously, **I do not** understand the relationship between "aspect" and "extent" from imshow(). Can somebody help me with this?

**Figure 1**

[image: fig1.png]

**Figure 2**

[image: fig2.png]

I was expecting both `fig1.png` and `fig2.png` to perfectly overlay on top of another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a memory profile with [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) for a sensible example, for 6M points.

```
import numpy as np
import time
x = np.random.normal(size=6000000)
y = np.random.normal(size=6000000)

start = time.time()
plt.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.1)
end = time.time() - start
print(end)
```

`out` is 30.015294551849365 seconds. It's not terribly slow.

On the other hand, the profile output:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
 5   81.738 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
 6                             def make_test():
 7  127.516 MiB   45.777 MiB       x = np.random.normal(size=6000000)
 8  173.293 MiB   45.777 MiB       y = np.random.normal(size=6000000)
 9                             
10  282.934 MiB  109.641 MiB       plt.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.1)
11  298.160 MiB   15.227 MiB       plt.savefig('big_plot')
```

It reaches up to 300 Mb, which is not a memory problem either.
The problem is elsewhere, but you should be able to plot **ALL** the points together.

Finally, the scatter plot:

[image: big_scatter_plot]

Comment: Thanks! I'll look over my script again. I might have missed something, but the the padding when loading the fig1.png using imshow() drives me nuts.How do i fdigure out why the png is not perfectly overlayed with the second figure? It was not my intent to get a plot in a plot ...

Comment: I do not find out what the problem is, but it's **NOT** a good idea. I suggest you do it differently.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your input. What i was trying to explain is that i do not want to see two sets of axes in the second figure if i want to plot-save-load-plot like i originally intended (with plotting only 3000 points at a time). The saved figure (Figure 1 above) doesn't get scaled properly and i end up with Figure 2 that has two sets of axis (one from the PNG and one from the newly created figure). There is some padding issue that i do not understand how it works with imshow(). Or i could modify my script as you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: try with `extent=[-1300,2200,-1300,1200]` in the second `imshow`. It's closer! Also you must use `transparent=True` with `savefig`, to make the background transparent (but the next image will cover the previous one). Anyway the points will be overlapped, and with such amount will be ugly.

Comment: Thanks! That makes more sense.